# Enviar array de archivos esta vacio al ser recibido en el backend

Tags: php, javascript, json, fetch

Estoy intentando enviar un json anidado el cual puede enviar imagenes con el metodo fetch pero cuando el backend lo recibe el json viene con los datos correspondientes excepto los de las imagens el estan vacios.

> **Frontend**   cantidad: "50"   categoria: "carnde de res"   descripcion: "dsadas"   idProducto: null   img: Array(2)
> 0: File {name: "descarga (1).jpg", lastModified: 1602791090708, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 15 2020
> 14:44:50 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 9883, …}
> 1: File {name: "descarga.jpg", lastModified: 1602791083811, lastModifiedDate: Thu Oct 15 2020
> 14:44:43 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 9673, …}   nombre: "carne de res"
> opcion: "agregar"   precio: "100"
>
> **Backend** array (size=8)   'opcion' => string 'agregar' (length=7)   'idProducto' => null   'nombre' => string 'carne de res' (length=12)
> 'precio' => string '100' (length=3)   'cantidad' => string '50'
> (length=2)   'categoria' => string 'carnde de res' (length=13)
> 'descripcion' => string 'dsadas' (length=6)   'img' =>
> array (size=2)
> 0 =>
> array (size=0)
> empty
> 1 =>
> array (size=0)
> empty

**javascript**

```
  let img = [];
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let opcion = form.getAttribute('modalTipo');
        let idProducto = form.getAttribute('idProducto');
        let nombre = document.getElementById('NombreInput').value;
        let precio = document.getElementById('PrecioInput').value;
        let cantidad = document.getElementById('CantidadInput').value;
        let categoria = document.getElementById('EtiquetasInput').value;
        let descripcion = document.getElementById('descripcionInput').value;
        
        data = {
            opcion: opcion,
            idProducto: idProducto,
            nombre: nombre,
            precio: precio,
            cantidad: cantidad,
            categoria: categoria,
            descripcion: descripcion,
            img: img
        };
        console.log(data);
        fetchData(data)
    });

document.getElementById('upload_input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if (this.files.length > 0) {
        let fileName = this.files[0].name;
        let exists = false;
        img.forEach(i => {
            if (i.name == fileName) {
                exists = true;
            }
        });
        if (!exists) {
            document.getElementById('content_files').append(fileName) ;
            img.push(this.files[0]);
            console.log(this.files);
        } else{
            console.log('ya existe esta imagen');
        }
    }
})
```

**Php**

```
include_once('./conexion.php');
include_once('./apis/apiAlmacen.php');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$opc = $obj['opcion'];
$idProducto = isset($obj['idProducto']) ? $obj['idProducto'] : ''; 
$nombre = isset($obj['nombre']) ? $obj['nombre'] : '';
$precio = isset($obj['precio']) ? $obj['precio'] : '';
$cantidad = isset($obj['cantidad']) ? $obj['cantidad'] : '';
$descripcion = isset($obj['descripcion']) ? $obj['descripcion'] : '';
$categoria = isset($obj['categoria']) ? $obj['categoria'] : '';
$img = isset($obj['img']) ? $obj['img'] : '';
var_dump($obj);
 var_dump($img);
```

Comment: El tema de los archivos en fetch se trata de modo distinto, te invito a leer [**La sección llamada enviando un archivo**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

Comment: No queda claro de donde viene `img` pero al parecer es un objeto asociado a un input de seelccion de archivos. En este caso, dichos objetos no se pueden enviar como parte de la data, se envian como parte de la data POST mediante encoding `multipart/form-data`. Peudes agregar la definicion/asignacion de `img`?

Comment: También del lado de PHP,  debes usar [**`$_FILES`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: ya subi la parte del codigo que tiene la que ver con la variable img

Comment: `if (!exists) {` <-- al revés, sin negarlo, debería ser `if (exists) {`

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolvi la duda que tenia. La cosa es que estaba haciendo un json stringify en el body del fetch y este al ser enviado al back enviaba el campo de img vacio. Lo que hice fue crear una variable con formdata y despues hacia un append con img y a los datos hacia un json stringify y despues un append al form data y quedo de la siguiente forma en como paso los datos a fetch:

```
var img = []
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData();
    for( let [i,file] of img.entries()){
        data.append(i,file)
    }
    let obj = {
        opcion: form.getAttribute('modalTipo'),
        idProducto: form.getAttribute('idProducto'),
        nombre: document.getElementById('NombreInput').value,
        precio: document.getElementById('PrecioInput').value,
        cantidad: document.getElementById('CantidadInput').value,
        categoria: document.getElementById('EtiquetasInput').value,
        descripcion: document.getElementById('descripcionInput').value
    };
    data.append('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
    fetchData(data);
});
```